# I have a UILabel in a UITableViewCell that monitors touch events, how do I pass some events to the cell and others to the label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UILabel` subclass that monitors its `touchesBegan` event to allow selection of links within the label (tapping a link in the label opens it in a webview).

Right now it passes the touch event to the `UITableViewCell` as well, causing it to be selected, which isn't ideal.

However in cases where they don't tap on a link, I do want it to be passed to the cell so they can select the cell to transition to the next view controller. This is like the behaviour in Tweetbot or Twitterrific or the like.

So how would I almost "selectively" pass the touch event? In my head it would almost be "if you're tapping on a link don't pass the touch on to the cell, but if you aren't tapping on a link this behaviour is fine".

Comment: If your label is handling the touches, then this touch should not be passed to the cell. When I try this, I don't see that pass through. Do you want the touch passed on if the user touches the label, but not on a word that's a link? How are you implementing the link?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm using TextKit for the label rendering, so I can use it to find the character I tapped on, then check the attributes for the character, where it's defined as a link. Turn on `userInteractionEnabled` to get the touch handling on the label. Reading further, is this not what `pointInside:withEvent` is for?

Comment: Or maybe `hitResult`?

Comment: I did get it to work with a textView, although I'm not sure it's the best way to go. In the textview's touchesBegan override, I search up through the subviews to get the cell and the table view so I can do the selection. If you think this could work for you, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @rdelmar Searching up the view hierarchy seems a little hacky. Especially given that I'd like this to work in cases other than a table view cell.

Comment: I don't know if I would call it hacky, but it seems like a violation of MVC. I do search by looking for a particular class though, so it could be adapted to other uses. I see in your comment to Michael's answer, mention of long press. Do you want long press behavior, or not (I assume you don't want the long press behavior you get with a text view)?

Comment: @rdelmar I'd love to have the ability to do a long press on it if possible, even if I have to do it manually with `NSTimer`. I'm trying to understand what [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) is doing to achieve this, as with `onlyCatchTouchesOnLinks` and seemingly `hitTest` it's able to produce the right behaviour.

Comment: I found a way with a text view that's doesn't require searching up through the superviews, so I've posted that. I don't know if you could add a long press gesture recognizer using this approach. I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I had some problems with making clickable links in `UILabel` (although the scenario was different than yours). I solved it by using a non-editable `UITextView` and setting its `attributedText`. Just remember to set `NSLinkAttributeName` where needed. I did a simple test and it doesn't pass clicks on a link to a `UIButton` behind it.

Comment: I can't use a `UITextView` for quite a few reasons, namely the difficulty/impossibility of watching touch down on the text view. But that's interesting, thanks. When you tap outside of the `NSLinkAttributeName`s does it then pass it to the button as it should?

Comment: Yes, it does pass tap to the button. What do you exactly want to achieve by tracking touch events? After a long press on a link in a `UITextView` it shows "Open / Copy / Add to reading list" menu, maybe that's sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I also found this library, its authors claim that it enables Tweetbot-like behavior: https://github.com/choefele/CCHLinkTextView

Comment: Interesting, I'll definitely have to take a look at that. But I do know it's possible with UILabel, as [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) uses it, seemingly through `hitTest`, but I can't seem to replicate it. My main issue with text views is that they "eat" the `touchesEnded` method, and have difficulty with long press gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this answer using a `UITextView` in case you don't get anything better to work. This actually works fine with very little code. In Apple's documentation, they say to call touchesBegan, etc. on super, and not to call it on the nextResponder, but the latter is what works. The text view is set to `selectable` but not `editable`. Scrolling has also been disabled. In the table view controller, I set the attributed text, and use the link attribute for any word I want to be a link. Here is the custom text view code,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}


-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

Setting `canBecomeFirstResponder` to `NO`, disables all the text view editor functions, so double taps, long presses, or tap and a half's (yes there is a tap and a half gesture recognizer) don't do anything.

In the table view controller, I need to set the delegate of the text view (to respond to the link tap), so I do this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textView.attributedText = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    cell.textView.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to post the corresponding project?